# MariaDB Pool Failed to Create Connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I'm facing this warning/error message that pops up every minute or so after running my Node project for 2-3mins. Been searching online but couldn't find any solution for this.

```
pool failed to create connection ((conn=-1, no: 45009, SQLState: 08S01) socket has unexpectedly been closed)
```

My db.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql"); //^2.18.1
const mariadb = require("mariadb"); //^2.5.3

const DB_OPTIONS = {
   host: "127.0.0.1",
   user: "root",
   password: "",
   database: "test-db",
   port: 3306,
   minDelayValidation: 5000
};

const connection = mariadb.createPool(DB_OPTIONS);

connection.getConnection().then((conn) => {
   console.log("Connected to DB!", conn.threadId);
   if (conn) conn.release();
}).catch((err) => {
   console.error("Error while connecting to DB", err);
});

module.exports = connection;
```

test.js

```
...
let database = require("./../middleware/db");
...
...
try 
{
   database.query(dbQuery, dbParameters).then((result) => {
      ...
   }).catch((dbCatchErr) => {
      ...
   })
}
catch (catchErr)
{
   console.error(catchErr);
}
```

MariaDB Version: 10.3.23